# Using pivot_longer to separate columns into long format

Tags: r

I have a df that is of non-finite length that looks like the table below.
The example here only has 2 traits: "lipids" and "density". Other rows may have 50 traits or more. But will always have the same pattern of trait, unit, method. When importing into R using read_excel it changes non unique names to xxx...[col.number]. I want to use pivot_longer to cast the data into a long format from wide. I'm having difficulty manipulating the function and would appreciate some help. The final column names I would like would be geno_name, observation_id, trait, value, unit, method

**Sample Data**
[image: Sample Data]

**Desired Output (without the drop_na statement to show example)**
[image]

```
x <- structure(list(geno_name = "MB mixed", observation_id = 10, lipids = NA, 
    unit...3 = NA, method...4 = NA, density = 1.125, unit...6 = "g cm^-3", 
    method...7 = "3D scanning"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-1L))
```

So far I have:

```
x %>% pivot_longer(
    cols = 3:ncol(x),
    names_to = c("trait","unit","method"),
    #need help with these other arguments
    values_drop_na = T)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data column names to be used in 'long' format doesn't all have the same pattern in column names.  Therefore, the steps included are

- rename columns that doesn't have the `...` or `_` in their column names by adding those with `paste/str_c`
- reshape to long format with `pivot_longer` - taking into account the pattern in names with either `names_sep` or `names_pattern`, specify the `names_to` as a vector of `c(".value", "trait")` in the same order we want the column values and the suffix value to be stored as separate columns
- Once we reshaped, create a grouping column based on the values in the 'trait' (some of them are numbers - create a logical vector and get the cumulative sum) along with the other grouping 'geno_name', 'observation_id' (which doesn't create a unique column though))
- Now `summarise` the other columns by slicing the first row after ordering based on NA elements i.e. if there are no NA, the first value will be non-NA or else it will be NA
- 

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
x %>%
   rename_at(vars(names(.)[!str_detect(names(.), "[_.]+")]), 
       ~ str_c("value...", .)) %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = 3:ncol(.), 
      names_to = c(".value", "trait"), names_sep = "\\.+") %>% 
   group_by(geno_name, observation_id, 
       grp = cumsum(str_detect(trait, "\\D+"))) %>%
   summarise(across(everything(), ~ .[order(is.na(.))][1]),
         .groups = 'drop') %>%
   select(-grp)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 6
#  geno_name observation_id trait   value unit    method     
#  <chr>              <dbl> <chr>   <dbl> <chr>   <chr>      
#1 MB mixed              10 lipids  NA    <NA>    <NA>       
#2 MB mixed              10 density  1.12 g cm^-3 3D scanning
```

#### data

```
x <- structure(list(geno_name = "MB mixed", observation_id = 10, lipids = NA, 
    unit...3 = NA, method...4 = NA, density = 1.125, unit...6 = "g cm^-3", 
    method...7 = "3D scanning"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

Comment: Thank you, but not quite what I'm intending. Looking for output to have the following column names:   geno_name, observation_id, trait, value, unit, method. with "density" and "lipids" being put into trait, the value for these columns into value, and the same idea for the respective unit and method

Comment: looking better but still not quite. 1) If you look at your output it has the wrong unit for lipids and no value for density units. 2) What if there are multiple traits in the table, and not just lipids and density? I do not know the name of each trait so I could use regex to identify the trait names using regex since it will be all column names that do not have "\\.{3}"

Comment: @Patrick well, this is based on your example.  If the patterns are different, you may need to show a representative example that shows all the patterns

Comment: This will return all traits: colnames(x) %>% .[!grepl("\\.{3}", .)] %>% tail(.,-2)

Comment: @Patrick I checked the update with your expected output.  It seems to be matching now

Comment: Excellent! Added a %>% drop_na() to the end to remove rows that have na's and thus have empty values. Tested on other data by adding other traits, units, and methods and works excellent. Thank you so much! Accepted as solution.

Comment: Is there an easy way to redo this if the column names are repeated? Using check.names = F for read.csv preserves non unique column names? New columns would be [trait_1], unit, method, [trait_2], unit, method. Where trait_1 and trait_2 are lipids and density in the above example. But as the current code does allows for infinite number of traits along the same 3 column pattern. Thanks, Patrick

Comment: @Patrick Is it possible for you to post as a new question so that it is easier to understand the issue you mentioned

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228496/discussion-between-patrick-and-akrun).